# Make a stored polyline editable again?

Tags: google-maps

I am bit stuck with making a saved polyline editable again. At the moment i have stored the points in a mysql database and i am able to show the route/polyline again with custom markers.

Now i like the polyline to be editable again and for this i was looking into:
http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html

Issues i have:

1. i can't get the already saved points/markers to act as if they where just placed on the map. For example the points can't be dragged and dropped. A marker can be picked up but i am not able to put it on the map again (i already tried event dragend).
2. i don't want the midmarkers, just the ability to move markers, add and delete markers

At the moment my startediting function looks like:

```
function startEditing(){

                if(editing === true){
                        stopediting();
                }else{
                routeCoords = theRoute.getPath();    
                //remove custom icons
                //setAllMap(null);
                if(routeCoords.length > 0){
                           for(var i = 0; i < routeCoords.length; i++) {
                                var marker = setmarkers(routeCoords.getAt(i));
                               //alert("marker: "+marker);
                               markers.push(marker);
                               /*if(i > 0) {
                                   var midmarker = setmidmarkers(routeCoords.getAt(i));
                                   midmarkers.push(midmarker);
                               }*/
                           }
                           editing = true;
                           jQuery('#btnEditing').removeClass('green');
                           jQuery('#btnEditing').val('Stop Editing').addClass('red');
                       }

                }
        }
```

and function setmarkers looks like

```
function setmarkers(point){
             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: map,
                icon: imageNormal,
                raiseOnDrag: false,
                draggable: true
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
                marker.setIcon(imageHover);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
                marker.setIcon(imageNormal);
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "drag", function() {

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i] === marker) {
                        theRoute.getPath().setAt(i, marker.getPosition());
                        movemidmarker(i);
                        //movemarker(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                routeCoords = theRoute.getPath();
                var stringtobesaved = marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6) + ',' + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6);
                pointsArray.splice(i,1,stringtobesaved);
            });

           ////#end markers van DB

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    if (markers[i] === marker && markers.length !== 1) {
                        marker.setMap(null);
                        markers.splice(i, 1);
                        theRoute.getPath().removeAt(i);
                        removemidmarker(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                routeCoords = theRoute.getPath();
                if(markers.length > 0) {
                    pointsArray.splice(i,1);

                }
            });


            return marker;

        }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to make your geometry editable is to set a property `editable: true`. When you like your shapes to be editable, you can quickly iterate each geometry (points, polygons etc) in your vector layer and set editable = true. Look at the example here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/user-editable-shapes

Another example [here](http://ubilabs.github.io/google.maps.polyline.edit/examples/advanced.html)

This will give you those boxes/anchors, later you can simply set editable to false on each geomtery.

For dragging markers, look [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/draggable-markers/draggable-markers.html?r=49).
**Snippet**

```
// Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
```

Comment: thx for thinking along. But in my case it's a polyline not a shape. It's for bicycle website where you can plot and save your route. So more like your second example, but there i am not able to add a point in edit mode. Will play around with your examples and snippets

Comment: you can add a point in a slightly different way,try dragging a middle(light gray) point, or extending the end points to the desired place and later adding a point where the end point was earlier. If you think this has answered your question , please mark it as answer .